# table() add and remove values

Tags: algorithm, r, hashtable

I'm trying to create an efficient table() calculation (get the frequency of each value in a vector). The difference from the ordinary table() function is that it needs to support adding and removing values without recalculating the whole table.

I thought of using a hash table. for add: look for the key, add 1 to the value. for remove: look for the key. if found: subtract 1 from value, if not found: add new key with value=1.

I was wondering if any of you have other ideas.

Example:

```
X

key  freq
1    3
2    5
3    2
8    1

remove(8)

key  freq
1    3
2    5
3    2


add(2)

key  freq
1    3
2    6
3    2
```

Any ideas for an efficient implementation?
Thanks in advance!

--EDIT--

My current code, if anyone is interested (also involves the calculation of shannon entropy)

```
create.freq.hash<-function(x)
{
  t<-table(x)

  h<-hash(names(t),as.numeric(t));
  return(h);

}

freq.hash.add<-function(hash,key)
{
  if(is.null(hash[[key]]))
  {
    .set(hash,key,+1)
  }
  else
  {
    .set(hash,key,hash[[key]]+1)
  }
}

freq.hash.remove<-function(hash,key)
{
  if(!is.null(hash[[key]]))
  {
    if(hash[[key]]==1)
      del(key,hash)
    else
      .set(hash,key,hash[[key]]-1)
  }
}

hash.entropy<-function(hash)
{
  if(is.empty(hash))
    return;

  v<-values(hash);
  v.prob<-v/sum(v);
  entropy = (-1)*(v.prob%*%log2(v.prob))
  return(entropy)
}
```

Comment: Depending on how dense you expect the counts to be, either use a named integer vector, or a regular integer vector.

Comment: There's no limitation of the counts (could be 1000s or more). How can I get the frequency using an integer vector? sorry if I'm missing something.

Comment: is this using the `hash` package?  There isn't such a function in base R as far as I can tell ... it would be interesting to compare performance between simply using a named integer vector as hadley suggests, and your solution

Comment: Yes. the hash package is being used here. I did some comparisons of Shannon entropy calculation using the suggested solution and using infotheo::entropy. the results are pretty much the same.

Comment: The counts don't matter - how many _values_ do you have? Are they dense or sparse? i.e. if you just put the counts into an integer vector according to their position, what percentage of the vector would be filled?

Comment: Since we're counting frequencies, the maximum number of values is n, if each value is distinct. In other cases it really depends on the distribution of the data, where the data can have any type of discrete distribution.